# Cluster de servidores em redes diferentes

Tags: apache, tomcat

estou configurando um cluster de servidores Tomcat8.

Os servidores já estão fazendo o balanceamento de carga (mod_jk), porém eu preciso implementar a alta disponibilidade (replicação de sessão).

Na documentação que eu tenho, o Tomcat é configurado para se comunicar via endereço MultCast (228.0.0.4), mas acredito que isso não sirva para mim, pois meus servidores estão em redes diferentes (ex: Server 1 - IP: 188.123.123.14 e Server 2 - IP: 62.123.123.21)

Alguém tem alguma dica?

Server.xml (fonte: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/cluster-howto.html)

```
<Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster" channelSendOptions="8">
    <Manager className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager" expireSessionsOnShutdown="false" notifyListenersOnReplication="true"/>
    <Channel className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.GroupChannel">
        <Membership className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastService" address="228.0.0.4" port="45564" frequency="500" dropTime="3000"/>
        <Receiver className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.NioReceiver" address="auto" port="4000" autoBind="100" selectorTimeout="5000" maxThreads="6"/>
        <Sender className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.ReplicationTransmitter">
            <Transport className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.PooledParallelSender"/>
        </Sender>
        <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.TcpFailureDetector"/>
        <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.MessageDispatch15Interceptor"/>
    </Channel>

    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve" filter=""/>
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve"/>

    <Deployer className="org.apache.catalina.ha.deploy.FarmWarDeployer"
        tempDir="/tmp/war-temp/"
        deployDir="/tmp/war-deploy/"
        watchDir="/tmp/war-listen/"
        watchEnabled="false"/>

    <ClusterListener className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.ClusterSessionListener"/>
</Cluster>
```

Comment: Esse link aqui ajuda?
https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/Clustering+CAS

Answer (score 1):

Acabei resolvendo meu problema usando o [Memcached](https://code.google.com/p/memcached/).

Sei que não é a melhor solução, uma vez que é como reinventar a roda, além de ser uma camada a mais. O caso é que resolveu!